# Creating FIFO SQS queue with cloudformation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I am trying to create a FIFO SQS queue (just learning); looking at the docs here http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-sqs-queues.html#aws-properties-sqs-queues-prop

My simple CF template is:

```
Resources:
  FifoQueue:
    Type: "AWS::SQS::Queue"
    Properties:
      FifoQueue: True
      QueueName: "FifoQueue.fifo"
```

I get the following error:  Unknown Attribute FifoQueue.

If I delete the last name, for the Queue Name, I get:The name of a FIFO queue can only include alphanumeric characters, hyphens, or underscores, must end with .fifo suffix and be 1 to 80 in length.

Anybody has an example of creating a FIFO queue with cloudformation ?

Comment: Which region are you using? FIFO queues are currently only available in Oregon and Ohio.

Comment: thanks @MattHouser; that is probably it !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check the documention and forums, it could be FIFO queues are [not available in all regions currently.](https://github.com/aws/aws-cli/issues/2549)

Answer (score 3):

Also, I see your Boolean flag is not correct, here is an example that works

```
{
    "AWSTemplateFormatVersion": "2010-09-09",
    "Description": "AWS CloudFormation Template for
    "Resources": {
        "MyFirstFIFO": {
            "Type": "AWS::SQS::Queue",
            "Properties": {
                "FifoQueue": true,
                "QueueName": "myfirstfifo.fifo"
            }
        }
    }
}
```